# get all the dates that fall between two dates

Tags: jquery, date

i have a problem where the user selects a range of dates. i need to then find out what dates fall between those two selected dates. they're coming in via jquery with something as simple as

`$('#from').val()+"-"+$('#to').val();`

they're coming from jqueryUI datepicker and they just look like

`08/07/2013 - 08/09/2012`

but i can't figure out how to step through the dates and determine which days in in between. i need the specific dates, but this becomes really complicated with things like the end of the month and different number of days in each month. in this specific example, i'd need to get

`08/07/2013, 08/08/2013, 08/09/2013`

Comment: "*They're coming from jQueryUI datepicker*" -- Any reason you can't use `getDate` and work with date objects instead? It'll make your life much easier.

Comment: if i have two date objects, how do i get every one in between?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can grab the values from your date pickers using the `getDate` method, since this will return you a Date object. Then, starting at the start date increment "current" date by 1 day and add it to an array until the current date is the same as the end date.

Note that you'll need to create a new Date() when adding it to the `between` array, or else you will just be referencing the `currentDate` object and all your values will be the same.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TMsXM/3)**

```
var start = $("#from").datepicker("getDate"),
    end = $("#to").datepicker("getDate"),
    currentDate = new Date(start.getTime()),
    between = []
;

while (currentDate <= end) {
    between.push(new Date(currentDate));
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
}
```

Comment: +1 but I think he's looking for `currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()) ;` and `while (currentDate <= end) `

Comment: @Icarus Not sure what you mean?

Comment: Your code doesn't include the actual selected dates. If you select 8/7 and 8/9 he wants to get 8/7, 8/8 and 8/9. Your code only pushes in the array 8/8. Follow?

Comment: @Icarus I see, so the between array only contains the dates between the selected dates. I guess that could be an issue, though the `start` and `end` variables have the selected values in them.

Comment: yes i want all the dates, but i believe i can fix that by using `start` to `between` to `end` and putting them together

Comment: @Icarus Good catch :) I updated the code and fiddle to add both the start and end dates

Comment: @cfs Could please amend a bit so it displays all the dates excluding the weekends (saturday/sundays)?

Comment: @user5173426 you're better off posting a new question than asking for this one to be changed. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
            //start of with getting the dates from your array 
                var between =[]
                for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfHolsInfoTbl.length; i++){
                    alert( holsInfoTblData[i].StartDate)
                    alert(holsInfoTblData[i].EndStart)
                    var datePickedStr1 = holsInfoTblData[i].StartDate;
                    var datePickedDate1 = new Date(datePickedStr1)//converts string to date object

                    var datePickedStr2 = holsInfoTblData[i].EndStart;
                    var datePickedDate2 = new Date(datePickedStr1)

                    while (datePickedDate1 <= datePickedDate2) {
                        between.push(new Date(datePickedDate1));
                        datePickedDate1.setDate(datePickedDate1.getDate() + 1);
                    }
                }
            //loop through array and print  all dates that have been added to array 
                for (var j = 0; j < between.length; j++) {
                    alert("This is all the dates " + between[j])
                }
```