# How can I display all the calendar dates in rails, for a selected year in years dropdown and selected month in months dropdown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar, format

I am having two dropdowns one is year dropdown which displays current year and 2 more years from current year. and I am having months dropdown which displays all 12 months. I want to display all calendar dates from 1st to 31st in this format ("Tue, 01-May-2015") for the user selected month in months dropdown and for the selected year in years dropdown.

How can I do that in rails?

Comment: paste your erb code of _form.html.erb

Comment: <%= select_month(Date.today) %>
<%= select_year(Date.today, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => 3.years.from_now.year) %>
iam having this code in my view.

Comment: use jquery datepicker

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="month"><%= select_month(Date.today, prompt: 'Choose month') %></div>
<div class="year"><%= select_year(Date.today, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => 3.years.from_now.year, prompt: 'Choose year') %></div>
```

```
<script>
    $(".date").hide();
    $('.date', '.month').change(function(e){
        var month = $('.month').val();
        var year = $('.year').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<controller>/get_dates",
            data: { month: month,  year: year},
            success: function( data ) {
                (".date").val(data);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

HTML file

controller

```
def get_dates
  params[:month] ||= Time.now.month
  params[:year] ||= Time.now.year
  @dates = Time.days_in_month(params[:month].to_i, params[:year].to_i)
end
```

Comment: Thanks @user123.  now the requirement has been changed. iam having the employee check_ins and check_outs in a table. currently iam displaying all months check-ins and check-outs of a logined employee with this curr_emp_attendace = current_employee.punch_in_outs. with normal html request.now when the user selects any month or year i need to make a ajax request, in that i need to write query like curr_emp_attendace = current_employee.punch_in_outs, for the selected month and year of the current employee.how to write this query and how to render the data in a div dynamically without page reload?

Comment: In check_ins table, what columns will be there?

Comment: emp_id(foreign key) ,check_in(datetime datatype) ,check_out(datetime datatype)

Comment: from month dropdowns iam getting the month value like (2) , from year drop down iam getting the year value like (2015) how can i query the table to retrieve the records of this selected month and year by using where clause to the query  something like this  curr_emp_attendace = current_employee.punch_in_outs where(year , month ) on the datetime coloumns (check_in, check_out)?

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to go with date picker

or else

`x = Date.today.beginning_of_year..Date.today.end_of_year
 => Thu, 01 Jan 2015..Thu, 31 Dec 2015`

Then use this `x.to_a` in your dropdown.

Edit:

Better way is still going with date picker.

Else you can do it with AJAX the following way

## html file

```
<script>

    $('#month_drop_down', '#year_drop_down').change(function(e){
        var month = $('#month_drop_down').val();
        var year = $('#year_drop_down').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<controller>/get_dates",
            data: { month: month,  year: year},
            dataType:'json',
            async:false,
            success: function( data ) {
                ("#date_div").html(data);
            }
        });
    });

</script>

<div>
       <div style="float:left;" id="date_div"><%= select_tag "date", [[1,1][2,2]....]) %>`
       <div style="float:left;" id="month_div"><%= select_tag "month_drop_down", [[1,1][2,2]....]) %>
       <div style="float:left;" id="year_div"><%= select_tag "year_drop_down", [[1,1][2,2]....]) %>
</div>
```

## Controller

```
def get_dates
    @x = Date.today.beginning_of_year..Date.today.end_of_year
    render :partial 'get_dates'

end
```

## _get_dates.html.erb

```
<%= select_tag "date", @x) %>
```

Don't define get_dates action in your routes.

Note: This code might not work by just copy-pasting, you will nedd to do some necessary editing to it.

Comment: there are two different drop downs for month and year

Comment: is it  ok if instead of showing three different drop downs for date, year and month, we will have one text field with datepicker?

Comment: thats anyways better, depends what requirements you have, and if it is not a mandate to go with threee dropdowns, go ahead with datepicker

Comment: @user123 ,actually the requirement is i should have 2 dropdowns one is year dropdown and other is months dropdown.when the months dropdown changes i need to get the dates of that particular month of the selected year.if no year is selected by default i need to take the current year.and i need to display the dates below the dropdowns.

Comment: ABove code will work fine for this, go through it and try to understand what we are doing with it. 

or else

Have a look at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18109481/get-all-the-dates-that-fall-between-two-dates,  
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp  and 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setfullyear.asp

These might help you