# disable specific dates within javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have javascript function

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var d = new Date();
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
today = monthNames[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getDate() + ' ' + d.getFullYear();

$('#to').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('#from').datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1d",
    beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates,
    minDate: "+1d",
    maxDate: "+3M",
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    showOtherMonths: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    required: true,
    altField: '#checkin',
    numberOfMonths: 1,
});

$('#from').change(function () {
    var from = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');
    var date_diff = Math.ceil((from.getTime() - Date.parse(today)) / 86400000);
    var maxDate_d = date_diff+7+'m';
    date_diff = date_diff + 1;
    $('#to').val('').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        minDate: date_diff,
        maxDate: maxDate_d,
        altField: '#checkout',
    });
});

$('#to').keyup(function () {
    $(this).val('');
    alert('Please select date from Calendar');
});
$('#from').keyup(function () {
    $('#from,#to').val('');
    $('#to').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    alert('Please select date from Calendar');
});
```

This  allows me to create JavaScript date select in form (check in and check out dates)

Function works perfect but here need one additional function to be integrated.

I want disable specific dates from - to I found this JavaScript and want to integrate in function above.

```
     var dakavebuli = 1000*60*60*24;
boloshesvla = new Date('2015-12-24');
bologasvla =  new Date("2015-12-25");
var shualeduritarigebi = (bologasvla.getTime()-          boloshesvla.getTime())/dakavebuli;


for(var i=0;i<=shualeduritarigebi; i++)
{
   var checking = boloshesvla.getTime()+dakavebuli*i;
   var checkout = new Date(checking);

   alert (checkout.getFullYear()+"-"+(checkout.getMonth()+1)+"-"+checkout.getDate());
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what the new javascript is supposed to do and what is the issue you found.

Comment: I have hotel reservation form and want to disable that dates wich already is taken

Answer (score 1):

The function you are using is not returning anything to the `datepicker` and hence will not block any such dates, you can use this function:

#### These are the dates stored in an array to be blocked.

```
var $myBadDates = new Array("10 October 2010","21 November 2010","12 December 2010","13 January 2011","14 February 2011","15 March 2011");
```

#### Function definition:

```
function DisableSpecificDates(mydate){
var $return=true;
var $returnclass ="available";
$checkdate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd MM yy', mydate);
for(var i = 0; i < $myBadDates.length; i++)
    {    
       if($myBadDates[i] == $checkdate)
          {
        $return = false;
        $returnclass= "unavailable";
        }
    }
return [$return,$returnclass];
}
```

Comment: I have two variables (from database) check in date ($dakavebulidan) and check out ($dakavebulimde) this looks like tgis : 2015-12-24 and 2015-12-25 first I want find dates between two dates and after disable oll

Comment: Yes you can loop between these two dates to get all dates, refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18109599/1496715

Comment: can you show finished function from that? I am new in javascript thanks!

Comment: I try but some errors here is live site url https://holidaylux.ge/en/rooms/items/item/6-holiday-lux-batumi2

Answer (score 0):

here is SOLUTION for this question

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var d = new Date();

var unavailableDates = [<?=$disabledays?>];

function unavailable(date) {
dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
    return [true, ""];
} else {
    return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
}
}


var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
today = monthNames[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getDate() + ' ' + d.getFullYear();

$('#to').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('#from').datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1d",
    beforeShowDay: unavailable,
    minDate: "+1d",
    maxDate: "+1M",
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    showOtherMonths: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    required: true,
    altField: '#checkin',
    numberOfMonths: 1,
});

$('#from').change(function () {
    var from = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');
    var date_diff = Math.ceil((from.getTime() - Date.parse(today)) / 86400000);
    var maxDate_d = date_diff+7+'m';
    date_diff = date_diff + 1;
    $('#to').val('').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        minDate: date_diff,
        maxDate: maxDate_d,
        beforeShowDay: unavailable,
        altField: '#checkout',
    });
});

$('#to').keyup(function () {
    $(this).val('');
    alert('Please select date from Calendar');
});
$('#from').keyup(function () {
    $('#from,#to').val('');
    $('#to').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    alert('Please select date from Calendar');
});
```

});