# Display a datepicker with dates lies between two given dates in jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a `start date = '02/08/2016'` , `end date = '20/08/2016'` . Now I need a result in `datepicker` such that, dates from `02/08/2016` to `20/08/2016`
should be displayed and all other past and later dates should be disabled.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: Combine the "Select a Date Range" and "Restrict Date Range" examples from the [official documentation](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this how you can achieve the dates between two dates. hope this may help you, as said by @cfs on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18109599/5813861), you can disable previous days by this script:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker,#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
        minDate:new Date()
    });
});
```

```
var start = $("#from").datepicker("getDate"),
    end = $("#to").datepicker("getDate"),
    currentDate = new Date(start.getTime()),
    between = []
;

while (currentDate <= end) {
    between.push(new Date(currentDate));
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
}
```

here's the fiddle to see [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yashsoni789/zdxtxk9u/)

Comment: THanks Yash,but, actually i need this as dates inside datepicker & not as a list. How can this be achieved.

Comment: means you have two date picker field in form , one for from date, when you choose from date, in "todate", previous date are disabled, and then select the todate. so where you want to set in between dates

Answer (score 0):

Simply use minDate and maxDate range function to set date range

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
            changeYear: true,
            minDate: '08/02/2016',
            maxDate: '20/08/2016'
        });
```